# join tables and search for data in two diff table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

Table 1: full

```
id name country street
1  ab   xx      xxx
2  bd   xx      xxx
3  dc   xx      xxx
```

Table 2: old_data

```
id language area_name  market_name
1  en       xx         xxx
2  cz       xx         xxx
```

Table 3 : new_data

```
id language area market
2  fr       xx   xxx
3  cz       xx   xxx
```

Now, With MySQL, I want to merge tables and find related details. 
Logic is : If not available in 'new_data' then only find it in 'old_data'

Output :

```
id name country street language area market
1  ab   xx      xxx    en       xx   xxx
2  bd   xx      xxx    fr       xx   xxx
3  dc   xx      xxx    cz       xx   xxx
```

Note : No of rows for Table 1 = No of rows for output table.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL`. If the value from `new_data` is null, use the value from `old_data` as the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `left join` the two tables, and then use `coalesce()` to pick the relevant values:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    coalesce(n.language, o.language) language,
    coalesce(n.area, o.area) area,
    coalesce(n.market, o.market) market
from table_full f
left join table_old_data on o.id = f.id
left join table_new_data n on n.id = f.id
```

This assumes that `language`, `area` and `market` are never `null`. If that's not the cas, then you can change the `coalesce()` expressions to:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    case when n.id is not null then n.language else o.language end language,
    case when n.id is not null then n.area else o.area end area,
    case when n.id is not null then n.market else o.market end market
from table_full f
left join table_old_data on o.id = f.id
left join table_new_data n on n.id = f.id
```

Comment: is there any other way ?? How much three coalesce and two joins cost ?

Comment: @lil-wolf: as far as concerns, that's the correct way to go. If your tables are properly indexed (or if `id` is a primary key in all 3 tables), then this should be quite efficient.